# How to autofill an HTML form through program without using manual effort?/

Tags: python, html, browser

I have a web page in the form  type of some portal, I need to fill around 1000 entries for the web portal so that i could complete the database for that portal, I want to know how can I fill these entries in an automated way so that the overburden of this works will be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the perfect use case for [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which is used for web browser automation. AFAIK it also has Python bindings so you can automate it using Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use urllib2 and post the data, (involves knowing the exact format of the url that results from pressing submit), or you could use the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library.

Then assuming that you have the data in something like a csv file you can automate the form filling.